# how I could allocate this struct? (C)

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a struct defined this way:

```
typedef struct _rule {
    char * patr_ent[100]; 
    int num_patr_ent; 
    char * plan_sal[100];
    int num_plan_sal; 
    int ult; 
} Rule;
```

And a variable consisting of an array of Rules:

```
Rule list_of_rules[100];
```

What I want to do is just: allocate memory for one "Rule" of list_of_rules -> modify the attributes of this Rule (print scan whatever) -> allocate for the next Rule, etc...

Should I do it this way?

```
Rule* list_of_rules; /* instead of  Rule list_of_rules[100] */
```

And allocate:

```
list_of_rules[0] = malloc (sizeof(struct _rule));
```

And then do the operations needed?

Answer (score 1):

In `C`, if you write `Rule list_of_rules[100];`, memory is allocated for every `Rule`.

---

If number of `Rule`s are not known at first:

```
Rule* list_of_rules;
int total=250;
list_of_rules=malloc (sizeof(struct _rule)*total);
```

Comment: yeah, this is thw way I have it right now, but what I want to do it's to allocate it using dinamic mem., since I don't know if I going to use 1 rule or 250

Comment: @user3263115 you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial proposition is ok:

```
Rule list_of_rules[100];
```

As said, your memory is already allocated.

You can also do this if you want to use malloc:

```
Rule * list_of_rules = malloc(100*sizeof(Rule));
```

**EDIT:** considering your comment, I guess you want something like this:

```
Rule * list_of_rules[100]; // List of POINTERS on Rule
for(unsigned int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
     list_of_rules[i] = malloc(sizeof(Rule));
}
```

Comment: And if I want to allocate into a loop? e.g. malloc list_of_rules[i] every iteration

Answer (score 0):

Why don't malloc only one struct and then use realloc each type you need to increase the size of the list_of_rules if you want a dynamic mem?
(sorry I can't add comment to the first answer)

EDIT
You can do this I think :

```
Rule* list_of_rules[100]; //Or any size needed

list_of_rules = (Rule**) malloc( 100*sizeof(Rule*) );

for(unsigned int i=0; i<100; ++i)
{
     list_of_rules[i] = (Rule*) malloc ( sizeof(Rule)) ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is OK:

```
Rule *list_of_rules = (Rule *)malloc(sizeof(Rule) * 100);
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

As replied earlier by @Rikayan-Bandyopadhyay

> In C, if you write Rule list_of_rules[100];, memory is allocated for every Rule.

But for dynamic memory allocation as you asked for you can allocate (increase currently allocated) memory using realloc() like

```
Rule* list_of_rules=NULL;
int ruleCounter=1;
/*For further dynamic allocation realloc can be used*/
while(<conditon to stop allocation>){
    list_of_rules= (Rule *)realloc(sizeof(Rule)*ruleCounter);
    /*list_of_rules[ruleCounter-1] is the new rule added dynamically.*/
}
```